# How to upscale my low res image to high res image using any software?

Tags: image, animation, graphics, resolution, photoshop

I have a low-res image in the attachments section, would anybody explain me technique to make it high-res image ? It would be really helpful if you could show me how can I improve resolution, quality and bring out the elements from the image clearly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to change the resolution upwards simply because your image lacks the data to do so. There is no program that would 'calculate' the pixels to more then there are. Ether find the source of the image and take a larger picture or have a higher resolution rendered. You could -trace- the image in illustrator and abandon the exact composition of the artwork.

Answer (score 0):

I know "Vector Magic" Paid software. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest tracing the image in illustrator and that way you will create a new image with higher pixel counts. It is not possible to "add" any pixels in your current image as it originally does not have additional pixels.

Also, please specify if you want to improve resolution while enlarging the picture or you wish to use it as the same size? This will help in getting a to the point answer.